# Swapping domains causes errors and broken links

Tags: php, drupal, dns, subdomain

I recently swap my domain. I pointed my new domain to the hosing DNS which are hosting my files. I added sub domains and pointing the correct root directory to each sub domains. So for so good. I browse the primary domain and all subdomains and they all shows my content; **HOWEVER** I now don't see my headers, layout is different and all links are broken on all my subdoamins...what happen here? Where did I go wrong and what do I need do?

Also, the main domain is programmed in Drupal (CMS) all links work perfectly and layout displays correctly.
All sub domains links are still pointing to my old domains.

here's my new domain

Main domain - http://bit.ly/kvqEEL (everything workings)

Amstaff- http://bit.ly/kB9tx0 (Broken links, banner/Header not displaying & Lay issues)

Please help....any comments or help would be much appreciated!!!

I am not a programmer please keep in mind when replying....Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using as a CMS on the subdomains? Whatever it is (a cms, plain files, etc...) has the old domain hardcoded within and you'll have to manually hack up everything to use the new domain.

Comment: I think you maybe right, Virtualpedigrees.com could be hard-coded into the CMS. My question now is....How do I change that? I am using hostgator, does anyone knows the name of the files or root files I need to edit...sorry I am a complete novices!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing some stylesheets. Double check to make sure all of your stylesheets are linked up correctly.

Also, your URL root is http://amstaff.pedigrees.co/ while most of your content is linking to http://amstaff.virtualpedigrees.com/ - you'll need to update all references in your code to the new root.

Comment: I believe so to Dave, but where can I go to update that info??

Answer (score 0):

All of the links in your code point to a .com, but your domain is now .co, those paths all need to be updated. If you have the site code on your computer, you can try a project-wide search and replace from "amstaff.virtualpedigrees.com" to "amstaff.virtualpedigrees.co".

Comment: I don't owned Virtualpedigrees.co the new domain is "pedigrees.co" and I need to update all records within the main root directory to "pedigrees.co so that the layouts and links work correctly. I use hostgator for hosting, where can I find the the root directory to change all old info?

Comment: You'll want to find your file manager and look for the folder called www or httpdocs or public_html or htdocs. It may take a long time to do it this way though. It would be preferable to download the entire site to your local computer and use a tool to do a search and replace across the entire folder.